# Is it possible to find the bending point using opencv Python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour

Aim of my program is find the angle of bending Led.

I got the angle using convexity defects in convex hull but the midpoint is move away from center point of that bend.

original image
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmkMB.png)

below image is the output of program

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLaxQ.png)

black dot is starting point.

red dot is end point.

blue dot is mid point.

Now I want move blue dot to the center of the curve

my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
from collections import OrderedDict

def findangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
    ria = np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) - np.arctan2(y3 - y1, x3 - x1)
    if ria > 0:
        if ria < 3:
            webangle = int(np.abs(ria * 180 / np.pi))
        elif ria > 3:
            webangle = int(np.abs(ria * 90 / np.pi))
    elif ria < 0:
        if ria < -3:
            webangle = int(np.abs(ria * 90 / np.pi))
            
        elif ria > -3:
            webangle = int(np.abs(ria * 180 / np.pi))
    return webangle



image = cv2.imread("cam/2022-09-27 10:01:57image.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours,hie= cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
selected_contour = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))
# Draw Contour
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(selected_contour, 0.0035 * cv2.arcLength(selected_contour, True), True)
for point in approx:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [point], 0, (0, 0, 255), 3)
convexHull = cv2.convexHull(selected_contour,returnPoints=False)
cv2.drawContours(image, cv2.convexHull(selected_contour), 0, (0, 255, 0), 3)
convexHull[::-1].sort(axis=0)
convexityDefects = cv2.convexityDefects(selected_contour, convexHull)
start2,distance=[],[]
for i in range(convexityDefects.shape[0]):
    s, e, f, d = convexityDefects[i, 0]
    start = tuple(selected_contour[s][0])
    end = tuple(selected_contour[e][0])
    far = tuple(selected_contour[f][0])
    start2.append(start)
    cv2.circle(image, start, 2, (255, 0, 0), 3)
    cv2.line(image,start,end , (0, 255, 0), 3)
    distance.append(d)
distance.sort(reverse=True)
for i in range(convexityDefects.shape[0]):
    s, e, f, d = convexityDefects[i, 0]
    if distance[0]==d:
       defect={"s":s,"e":e,"f":f,"d":d}
cv2.circle(image, selected_contour[defect.get("f")][0], 2, (255, 0, 0), 3)
cv2.circle(image, selected_contour[defect.get("s")][0], 2, (0, 0, 0), 3)
cv2.circle(image, selected_contour[defect.get("e")][0], 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
x1, y1 = selected_contour[defect.get("f")][0]
x2, y2 = selected_contour[defect.get("e")][0]
x3, y3 = selected_contour[defect.get("s")][0]
cv2.line(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,200,0),2)
cv2.line(image,(x1,y1),(x3,y3),(255,200,0),2)
cv2.putText(image, "Web  Angle : " + str((findangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3))), (50, 200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow("frame",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

so i want any concept to get exact center of the bend point.

Comment: Define exact bend point?  Do you mean the point of maximum curvature? Get the curve points and find the slope along every point. Then find the change in slope from point to point. Find that point that has the maximum change in slope. More specifically see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature

Comment: what you mean by define exact bend point. you mean should i need to define the exact coordinate point in program? i don't know what is curvature. An how to find the maximum curvature of that curve?

Comment: By bend point, do you mean maximum curvature or something else. Define it mathematically or functionally.  There are lots of points between the two straight sections. Where on that curve do you mean?

Comment: Draw the two straight lines and find where they intersect. Then drop a perpendicular line to the curve to find the point of intersection on the curve. That could be your "bend point"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV. I make no guarantees that it is universal and would work on all such images. I also leave it for others to add trapping for empty arrays/lists and other general best practices.

- Read the input
- Threshold to binary on white using cv2.inRange()
- Apply morphology to close up the gap near the top
- Skeletonize the binary image
- Get the x and y coordinates of the points of the skeleton
- Zip the x and y coordinates
- Sort the zipped data by x
- Sort another copy of the zipped data by y
- Get the first line (end points) from the top for 40% of y from the y sorted data, since that region of the skeleton is nearly straight
- Get the first line (end points) from the left for 40% of x from the x sorted data, since that region of the skeleton is nearly straight
- Get the intersection point of these two lines
- Compute the x and y derivatives of the x coordinates and the y coordinates, respectively
- Loop over each point and compute the slope from the derivatives, which will be tangent to the skeleton at the point
- Then still in the loop compute the inverse slope of the line from the point to the previously computed intersection point. This will be normal (perpendicular) to this line.
- Compute the difference in slopes and find the point where the difference is minimum.  This will be the bend point.
- Draw relevant lines and points on skeleton and input
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.morphology

img = cv2.imread("wire.png")

# create a binary thresholded image
lower = (255,255,255)
upper = (255,255,255)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
thresh = (thresh/255).astype(np.float64)

# apply morphology to connect at top
kernel = np.ones((11,11), np.uint8)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# apply skeletonization
skeleton = skimage.morphology.skeletonize(thresh)
skeleton = (255*skeleton).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# get skeleton points
pts = np.where(skeleton != 0)
x = pts[1]
y = pts[0]
num_pts = len(x)
print(num_pts)

# zip x and y
xy1 = zip(x,y)
xy2 = zip(x,y)

# sort on y
xy_sorty = sorted(xy1, key = lambda x: x[1])
#print(xy_sorty[0])

# sort on x
xy_sortx = sorted(xy2, key = lambda x: x[0])
#print(xy_sortx[0])
 
# unzip x and y for xy_sortedy
xu1, yu1 = zip(*xy_sorty)

# get first line from top
# find miny from y sort, then get point 40% down from miny
miny = np.amin(yu1)
y1 = miny
[xy1] = [(xi, yi) for (xi, yi) in xy_sorty if abs(yi - y1) <= 0.00001]
x1 = xy1[0]
y1 = xy1[1]
#print(x1,y1)
maxy = np.amax(yu1)
dely = maxy - miny
y2 = int(y1+0.4*dely)
[xy2] = [(xi, yi) for (xi, yi) in xy_sorty if abs(yi - y2) <= 0.00001]
x2 = xy2[0]
y2 = xy2[1]
#print(x2,y2)

# unzip x and y for xy_sortedx
xu2, yu2 = zip(*xy_sortx)

# get first line from left
# find minx from x sort, then get point 40% right from minx
minx = np.amin(xu2)
x3 = minx
[xy3] = [(xi, yi) for (xi, yi) in xy_sortx if abs(xi - x3) <= 0.00001]
x3 = xy3[0]
y3 = xy3[1]
#print(x3,y3)
maxx = np.amax(xu2)
delx = maxx - minx
x4 = int(x3+0.4*delx)
[xy4] = [(xi, yi) for (xi, yi) in xy_sortx if abs(xi - x4) <= 0.00001]
x4 = xy4[0]
y4 = xy4[1]
#print(x4,y4)

# draw lines on copy of skeleton
skeleton_lines = skeleton.copy()
skeleton_lines = cv2.merge([skeleton_lines,skeleton_lines,skeleton_lines])
cv2.line(skeleton_lines, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.line(skeleton_lines, (x3,y3), (x4,y4), (0,0,255), 2)

# get intersection between line1 (x1,y1 to x2,y2) and line2 (x3,y3 to x4,y4) and draw circle
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line–line_intersection
den = (x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4)
px = ((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(x3-x4) - (x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/den
py = ((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/den
px = int(px)
py = int(py)
cv2.circle(skeleton_lines, (px,py), 3, (0,255,0), -1)

# compute first derivatives in x and also in y
dx = np.gradient(x, axis=0)
dy = np.gradient(y, axis=0)

# loop over each point
# get the slope of the tangent to the curve
# get the inverse slop of the line from the point to the intersection point (inverse slope is normal direction)
# get difference in slopes and find the point that has the minimum difference
min_diff = 1000000
eps = 0.0000000001
for i in range(num_pts):
    slope1 = abs(dy[i]/(dx[i] + eps))
    slope2 = abs((px - x[i])/(py - y[i] + eps))
    slope_diff = abs(slope1 - slope2)
    if slope_diff < min_diff:
        min_diff = slope_diff
        bend_x = x[i]
        bend_y = y[i]
        #print(x[i], y[i], min_diff)
bend_x = int(bend_x)
bend_y = int(bend_y)
#print(bend_x, bend_y)
cv2.line(skeleton_lines, (px,py), (bend_x,bend_y), (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.circle(skeleton_lines, (bend_x,bend_y), 3, (0,255,0), -1)

# get end points and bend point and draw on copy of input
result = img.copy()
end1 = (x1,y1)
end2 = (x3,y3)
bend = (bend_x,bend_y)
print("end1:", end1)
print("end2:", end2)
print("bend:", bend)
cv2.circle(result, (end1), 3, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(result, (end2), 3, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.circle(result, (bend), 3, (0,0,255), -1)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("wire_skeleton.png", skeleton)
cv2.imwrite("wire_skeleton_lines.png", skeleton_lines)
cv2.imwrite("wire_result.png", result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("thresh", (255*thresh).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imshow("skeleton", skeleton)
cv2.imshow("skeleton_lines", skeleton_lines)
cv2.imshow("skeleton_result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Skeleton:

[image]

Skeleton with lines:

[image]

Result showing end points and bend point:

[image]

Comment: thank for your hard work sir

Comment: I check with real time