# How to find the start,end,center point using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I want start,center,end point the curve.

I got more point using convexity defects(convex hull).

output image
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xXwP.jpg)

original image
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtwWc.jpg)

I don't have idea how to find that

this type of output image
[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtHMM.jpg)

my program

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

image = cv2.imread("2022-09-27 10:01:57image.png") 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours,hie= cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
selected_contour = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))
convexHull = cv2.convexHull(selected_contour,returnPoints=False)
convexHull[::-1].sort(axis=0)
convexityDefects = cv2.convexityDefects(selected_contour, convexHull)

for i in range(convexityDefects.shape[0]):
    s, e, f, d = convexityDefects[i, 0]
    cv2.circle(image, start, 2, (255, 0, 0), 3)
    cv2.line(image,start,end , (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow('frame', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Get the contour of your curve. Then get the medial axis (skeleton) line. Then get the end points.  From all the points along the curve, find the point with highest curvature as your center. See skimage.morphology.skeletonize for example.  OpenCV has something similar, see cv2.ximgproc.thinning()

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73865288/if-any-possible-to-find-the-bending-point-using-opencv-python

Comment: how to find the highest curvature point from center of the curve.

Comment: Get all points along the curve. Then get the x and y differences between points. Get the slope from those. Now get the differences in slope. Find the point with the largest difference in slope. The slope is like the first derivative, the difference in slope is like the second derivative. So alternately use the formula  for curvature in the wikipedia page and find the largest curvature.